# Google translate API - too many characters being sent - how to debug?

Tags: php, api, translate

I am using this script (https://github.com/viniciusgava/google-translate-php-client) to pass translation of text to Google. The text is generated through a script I coded myself.

The problem is that, Google is saying I'm passing 1-3k more characters than I actually am. I have gone through and made sure the loops are tight, commented out any sections that could possibly be leaking to test, but no matter what, it's passing too many characters.

Also, I tested doing this:

```
$text = (strlen($string) > 2000) ? substr($string, 0, 2000) . '...' : $string;
```

Even so, Google is saying I sent 3,300 characters.

My question is, how can I debug what's actually being sent to Google so I can identify the "leak"? How can I retrieve a list of everything that has been sent?

Note: The script I use for character counting (http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/charcount.shtml) already includes whitespaces, html and punctuation when counting the amount of characters.

Thank you for the help.

Update:
I ran a test completely separate from my script, I input 550 words in raw $string = "words"; format... ran the translation, and Google is reporting 1000! So the same thing is happening... I'm wondering if it's something to do with the script itself.

Update 2:
I ran a test using the official GTranslate API script, with 60 characters, Google recorded it as 100 characters. So something is happening that's doubling my characters, even on the official script.

Comment: First, [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) might help you capture the output. Second, are you trying to translate a two-byte character set like Japanese or Chinese? That linked counting script counts characters, but Google may be counting raw bytes; for example, it says 日本語 is three characters, but Google may be looking at the underlying 6 raw bytes.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Nope, I'm translating English -> Other Language. I am checking out Charles now.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Okay... interesting development. I ran a test completely separate from my script, I input 550 words in raw $string = "words"; format... ran the translation, and Google is reporting 1000! So the same thing is happening... hmm

Comment: Maybe your string is all Unicode/UTF16? Is that how PHP works under the hood? I cannot really help you more on this.

Comment: @Ken Y-N String is in a Notepad++ file that's UTF-8. Alright, I understand, thank you for the help and recommendation.